# Sequelize .save - undefined is not a constructor

Tags: postgresql, promise, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js

I am trying to save some data to a Postgres database using Sequelize. This is my code to connect to the database and create the model:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize'

const getModels = Connection => {
  return {
    User: Connection.define('users', {
      id: { type: Sequelize.STRING, primaryKey: true },
      refresh_token: { type: Sequelize.STRING }
    })
  }
}

const getInstance = () => {
  const Connection = new Sequelize(
    process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
      dialect: 'postgres',
      logging: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? false : console.log,
      omitNull: true,
    }
  )
  return getModels(Connection)
}

export default getInstance
```

I am trying to save the user `id` and `refresh_token` when the user logs in (authenticating using Auth0). Here is my code to do this:

```
const {User} = getInstance()
const user = User.build({ id: user_id, refresh_token: refresh_token })
user.save().then(() => {
  console.log('save completed')
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(`Something went wrong: ${error}`)
})
```

I am getting this error: `Something went wrong: TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new net.Stream()')`

If I do `console.log(user.id)` or `user.refresh_token` I get the correct info back so the `.build` function is working. Something is wrong with the save function though. Thanks for any help in solving it - I am using a React app with Webpack (plus server-side rendering); I'm getting some warnings about dependencies from Webpack due to Sequelize as I'm using it on the front-end, not back-end. If anyone has any ideas on how to fix these, that'd be great:

```
[0] ./~/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js
[0] Critical dependencies:
[0] 686:60-73 the request of a dependency is an expression
[0]  @ ./~/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js 686:60-73
[0] ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/mssql/connection-manager.js
[0] Critical dependencies:
[0] 18:15-71 the request of a dependency is an expression
[0]  @ ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/mssql/connection-manager.js 18:15-71
[0] ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js
[0] Critical dependencies:
[0] 18:17-60 the request of a dependency is an expression
[0]  @ ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js 18:17-60
[0] ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js
[0] Critical dependencies:
[0] 20:14-57 the request of a dependency is an expression
[0]  @ ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js 20:14-57
[0] ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/connection-manager.js
[0] Critical dependencies:
[0] 22:15-71 the request of a dependency is an expression
[0]  @ ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/connection-manager.js 22:15-71
[0] webpack built 3215b07a25217c8e67e0 in 13519ms
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check the user model primary key type?
It should be `Sequelize.INTEGER` not `Sequelize.STRING`

Comment: Hi @maheshiv, changed that and the data I was entering to Integers but it didn't work unfortunately. Thanks for suggesting it though!

Comment: can you `console.log(User);` to see if it actually returns your model or just `console.log(user);` to see the build